# Caliburn.Micro action bubbling with MenuItem and different ViewModels

Tags: c#, mvvm, menuitem, caliburn.micro

I create a menu user control view, and i want reuse that menu inside other view using Action bubbling. So my idea was, use x:Name element of every MenuItems, and declare the function in the MasterView.
Here is the code:

```
//MenuView.xaml
<UserControl x:Class="CaliburnTestApp.MenuView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org">
    <Grid >
        <Menu  IsMainMenu="True">
            <MenuItem  Header="_File" >
                <MenuItem Header="_New..."  x:Name="MenuItem_New"/>
                <MenuItem Header="_Open..." x:Name="MenuItem_Open"/>
                <Separator />
                <MenuItem Header="_Save" x:Name="MenuItem_Save"/>
                <MenuItem Header="_Save As..." x:Name="MenuItem_SaveAs"/>
                <Separator />
                <MenuItem Header="_Close"   cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action MenuItem_Close()]"/>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="?">
                <MenuItem Header="_Help" x:Name="MenuItem_Help" />
                <MenuItem Header="_About" x:Name="MenuItem_About" />
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        <Button Content="Button" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action MenuItem_Close()]"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="123,-1,-99,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

and its ViewModel

```
//MenuViewModel.cs
class MenuViewModel
{
    public MenuViewModel()
    {}

    public void MenuItem_Help()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MenuItem_Help Clicked");
    }
}
```

And here the container:

```
//SetupView.xaml
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="CaliburnTestApp.SetupView"
 Height="703.693" Width="813" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"   >
<Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="#FF837F80">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="487"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="111*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="90"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ContentControl  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  x:Name="MenuView" VerticalAlignment="Top" />

    </Grid>
```

And its SetupViewModel class

```
//SetupViewModel.cs
public interface ISetup {}
class SetupViewModel : Screen, ISetup
{
    MenuViewModel _menu;

    public MenuViewModel MenuView
    {
        get { return this._menu; }
        set { this._menu = value; this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(); }
    }

    public SetupViewModel()
    {
        this._menu = new MenuViewModel();
    }

    public void MenuItem_Close()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MenuItem_Close");
    }
}
```

The problem is the MenuItem Close get expection when clicked "No target found for method MenuItem_Close." 
But using the button close, the function MenuItem_Close() inside SetupViewModel is called correctly.
So i don't understand where is the error.

Comment: it's related to visual tree issues since the menu isn't in the visual tree at binding by CM it dies ever so loudly.  ````<MenuItem  cm:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding ElementName="UserControlsName" Path=Datacontext}" />```` should work or traverse the relativesource etc.  You might have to name your UserControl something x:Name="MenuControl" for example... CM will ignore it as long as you don't have something named "MenuControl" in the viewmodel.

Comment: @mvermef I add the  `x:Name="MenuControl"` inside <UserControl> and change the close button like this:                
`<MenuItem Header="_Close"  cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding ElementName=MenuControl, Path=DataContext}" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action MenuItem_Close()]"/>`
But i get the same error. No target found.

Comment: after reading more closely, it has do with menuviewmodel.cs, the menu is looking for that method signature.  You can try  the x:Name on the actual Menu, if that doesn't work put the TargetWithoutContext on the Menu as well.

Comment: No work. Always the same error.

Comment: Is setupviewmodel a member property of the MasterViewModel?

Comment: The MasterVM is the ShellViewModel that have a private readonly SetupViewModel _setupForm;

Comment: So you are injecting SetupViewModel in the constructor and assigning from there, are you using a ContentControl to get it on the screen?

Comment: Yes, i'm injecting the SetupVM in the constructor. No ContentControl, becouse i use IWindowManager. So there's  a button that call  _windowManager.ShowDialog(_setupForm, null, null); where the _setupForm is the SetupVM.